# Parse Onlineshop - Onlineshop Data

Tags: web-scraping, export-to-csv, extract, online-store

I am searching for a solution for crawling % parsing a whole website (online shop) automatically and save all products as Product-name and product-price in a CSV.

Answer (score 0):

Gaining data from a website can be extremely simple or the complete opposite. It depends on how the website is made. A shop tends to be a complex website and thus the DOM (the HTML structure) is mostly unique for that website. It is very unlikely that someone else tried the exact same thing you want for that page. So you have to write code and extract the necessary piecs.

This will be our example product: http://www.thomann.de/gb/focusrite_scarlett_2i2.htm

HTML uses classes to tell the CSS (for styling) how to design or render a certain element. You can use this behaviour for you and find an element containing the price by a class. In this example it is `.tr-prod-price`.

Every major browser has a *Discover element* function and it can be used to find a class for a element which appears on screen. Make a right click on your text (price or title) press Q (Firefox only).

Now, you've got closer to parsing your data. Now it is time to write code. You could use Python, Java or even JavaScript to give you some examples. JavaScript in conjunction with Node.JS could be very easy, because JS has the built in methods we need.

You may need a searchengine to find the detail pages of a product. Google can list you all results like [site:thomann.de/gb](https://www.google.com/#q=site:thomann.de%2Fgb). But of course Google does not provide an easy way (API) to get this information and if you start writing your own parser for that I am not sure about the legal consequences. The legal side needs also to be adressed for you main intention.